# Missing refresh_token when using authorization code with PKCE

Tags: pkce, tapkey

after authorizing the management api using the oauth2 code flow with PKCE the response from `POST https://login.tapkey.com/connect/token` do not return a refresh token. Am I missing something?

The redirect for the user goes to `https://login.tapkey.com/connect/authorize?client_id=[...]&redirect_uri=[...]&scope=write%3Agrants&response_type=code&state=[...]&code_challenge=[...]&code_challenge_method=S256"`

After the callback I'm requesting `POST https://login.tapkey.com/connect/token` with the following form data:

```
 [
  "grant_type" => "authorization_code"
  "client_id" => "[...]"
  "client_secret" => null
  "code" => "[...]"
  "redirect_uri" => "[...]"
  "code_verifier" => "[...]"
]
```

The response I get is

```
[
  "access_token" => "[...]"
  "expires_in" => 3600
  "token_type" => "Bearer"
  "scope" => "write:grants"
]
```

Comment: Can you please add your requests as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like described here https://developers.tapkey.io/api/authentication/pkce/#refreshing-an-access-token, for getting a refresh_token you also need to request the scope "offline_access".

Comment: Yes! I was just blind reading the documentation. Thanks!